# How can I check when was my last Lambda's run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

Which AWS lambda API/CLI will return to me the time and date in which my lambda was the last run?

Comment: Simple answer: It is not available. You could either track it yourself or examine CloudTrail to find it.

Comment: You can check the Lambda invoke history using Cloudwatch Metrics

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-invocation

To check this metric using the CLI, check the `aws cloudwatch get-metric-data` command. More info here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html